# for n factors with k levels each and one response variable, fill an n-array with the outputs of some function over the factor combinations

Tags: arrays, r

Assume the factors are the integers from `1` to `k`, so we can treat them as indices to an n-matrix. get each subset of data points that matches some combination of levels, apply a function over all of the response values, and place the output in the matrix element that corresponds to the factor combination.

For example, for the following data and the function `sum()`.

```
f1 f2 y
1 2 4
1 1 3
1 1 2
2 1 3
```

->

```
5 4
3 0
```

The only way I know how to do this is with loops. Also, the solution needs to work with any function, not just `sum`.

Comment: ...which can be shortened to `xtabs(y ~ ., data=dat)` if there's only the 3 variables shown. Pretty sure this is a duplicate question though.

Comment: @thelatemail, How does this work for other functions? I only chose `sum` because its a simple example, but I need it for other functions, such as `mean`.

Comment: I think the `tapply(dat[,"y"], dat[c("f1","f2")], mean)` suggestion is the simplest way to go.

Comment: @thelatemail yeah I think so too. But, I realised I should have phrased the question to account for missing levels, which will cause missing rows/columns from the matrix.